# Output J48 Tree in Text File in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, rweka

I have got the `decision tree` for `churn` data set using `J48()`function from `RWeka` package. The tree is really big hence I am unable to see the whole tree. I want to output it in a text file but the format is getting changed. How can I save it preserving the tree format.

`save(m2,file="thisexample.txt", ascii=TRUE)`

`m2` is the `dataframe` in which I am storing the `J48` tree output.

Comment: As a text file? What exactly would that look like? It would help if your example were [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)  with some sample input so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: I just want it in a format which i can open and see the tree structure as the output in dataframe is too big to come in a single screen in R.  On page 4 of this link,  my output also looks like it - https://www.erpublication.org/admin/vol_issue1/upload%20Image/IJETR032129.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I. Example with `iris` data set using `RWeka`'s `J48()` function.

```
      library(RWeka)
      result = J48(Species~.,data=iris)
      result
      # J48 pruned tree
      # ------------------

      # Petal.Width <= 0.6: setosa (50.0)
      # Petal.Width > 0.6
      # |   Petal.Width <= 1.7
      # |   |   Petal.Length <= 4.9: versicolor (48.0/1.0)
      # |   |   Petal.Length > 4.9
      # |   |   |   Petal.Width <= 1.5: virginica (3.0)
      # |   |   |   Petal.Width > 1.5: versicolor (3.0/1.0)
      # |   Petal.Width > 1.7: virginica (46.0/1.0)

      # Number of Leaves  :     5

      # Size of the tree :      9
```

II. Use `sink()` function to write it in a text file

```
      sink("result.txt")
      print (result)
      sink()
```

III. Open `result.txt` saved in your current working directory.

[image]